# How to filter the below log file between time stamps

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep, sed, awk

```
Wed Nov 15 11:02:07 CET 2017
last pid: 13243;  load averages:  1.45,  1.18,  1.04  up 7+19:11:10    11:02:07
82 processes:  1 running, 78 sleeping, 2 stopped, 1 zombie

Mem: 2157M Active, 1244M Inact, 293M Wired, 70M Cache, 62M Buf, 129M Free
Swap: 6144M Total, 2063M Used, 4081M Free, 33% Inuse


  PID USERNAME       THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME    WCPU COMMAND
82286 root           118  20    0   831M   247M STOP    0  12:48   0.00% python
 1354 root             1  22    0   707M   277M getblk  0 370:38   2.98% reportd
 1838 root             1  20    0   673M   145M kqread  0   2:26   0.00% reportqueryd
 1839 root             1  20    0   631M   167M kqread  0   3:38   0.00% reportd_helper
 1843 root             1  22    0   587M   296M kqread  1 814:52   2.98% hermes
26929 root             8  20    0   501M   300M STOP    0   4:38   0.00% content_scanner
 1352 root             1  21    0   490M   182M kqread  1  17:11   0.00% gui
18199 root             9  20    0   470M   127M sbwait  0   1:59   0.00% sophos
14545 root             8  20    0   449M   129M sbwait  0   2:54   0.00% mcafee
 1591 root            26  20    0   432M   189M uwait   0  56:34   0.00% splunkd
13185 spamd            1  52    0   423M   388M sbwait  0   0:02   0.00% parl
13186 spamd            1  25    0   423M   387M select  0   0:02   2.98% parl
13184 spamd            1  21    0   423M   387M accept  1   0:02   0.98% parl
13005 root             1  20    0   423M   387M nanslp  0   0:20   0.00% parl
 1322 root             1  20    0   371M 78420K kqread  0   2:13   0.00% euq_server
 1307 root             1  20    0   369M 71824K kqread  0   1:43   0.00% euq_webui
 1082 root             1  20    0   325M 27648K kqread  1   5:18   0.00% interface_controlle
 1323 root             1  20    0   325M 81428K kqread  1  26:41   0.00% updaterd
 2042 root             1  20    0   311M 17332K kqread  1   3:26   0.00% thirdparty
 1003 root             1  20    0   311M 73132K kqread  1  54:30   0.00% commandd
 1306 root             1  20    0   307M  5364K kqread  0   0:18   0.00% local_authd
 1303 root             1  20    0   305M  7436K kqread  0   0:21   0.00% ftpd.main
 1305 root             1  20    0   301M  1528K kqread  1   0:03   0.00% slbl_db_server
 1837 root             1  20    0   215M 43284K kqread  1   7:01   0.00% counterd
  981 root             1  47    0   196M 17936K kqread  0  10:52   0.00% heimdall
 1353 root             1  20    0   190M 15536K kqread  1   8:18   0.00% trackerd
 2048 root             1  20    0   190M 11036K kqread  0   0:19   0.00% sntpd
 1010 root             1  20    0   188M  6364K kqread  0   0:25   0.00% qlogd
 1308 root             1  20    0   188M  5184K kqread  0   0:18   0.00% ipblockd
 1304 root             1  20    0   188M  4576K kqread  0   0:13   0.00% gatherer
 1669 root             1  20    0   184M  9156K piperd  1   0:01   0.00% external_auth_log
 1478 root             1  20    0   184M  4888K kqread  0   0:13   0.00% ginetd
 2047 root             1  20    0   165M  8780K kqread  1   0:11   0.00% msgs_db_server
  733 root             1  20    0   149M 15484K kqread  1   0:03   0.00% raid_log_watch


Wed Nov 15 11:03:07 CET 2017
last pid: 13464;  load averages:  0.94,  1.12,  1.03  up 7+19:12:10    11:03:07
80 processes:  1 running, 76 sleeping, 2 stopped, 1 zombie

Mem: 2213M Active, 1196M Inact, 292M Wired, 59M Cache, 62M Buf, 133M Free
Swap: 6144M Total, 2065M Used, 4079M Free, 33% Inuse


  PID USERNAME       THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME    WCPU COMMAND
82286 root           118  20    0   831M   247M STOP    0  12:48   0.00% python
 1354 root             1  21    0   707M   277M bo_wwa  1 370:40   1.95% reportd
 1838 root             1  20    0   673M   145M kqread  1   2:26   0.00% reportqueryd
 1839 root             1  20    0   631M   167M kqread  0   3:38   0.00% reportd_helper
 1843 root             1  22    0   603M   299M kqread  1 814:54   2.98% hermes
26929 root             8  20    0   501M   304M STOP    0   4:38   0.00% content_scanner
 1352 root             1  21    0   490M   182M kqread  0  17:11   0.00% gui
18199 root             9  20    0   470M   116M sbwait  0   1:59   0.00% sophos
14545 root             8  20    0   449M   118M sbwait  1   2:54   0.00% mcafee
 1591 root            26  20    0   432M   189M uwait   0  56:34   0.00% splunkd
13185 spamd            1  20    0   425M   390M accept  1   0:02   0.00% parl
13184 spamd            1  29    0   423M   387M accept  1   0:04   0.00% parl
13186 spamd            1  21    0   423M   387M accept  1   0:04   0.00% parl
13005 root             1  20    0   423M   387M nanslp  1   0:20   0.00% parl
 1322 root             1  20    0   371M 78408K kqread  1   2:13   0.00% euq_server
 1307 root             1  20    0   369M 71796K kqread  1   1:43   0.00% euq_webui
 1082 root             1  20    0   325M 27648K kqread  1   5:18   0.00% interface_controlle
 1323 root             1  20    0   325M 80596K kqread  1  26:41   0.00% updaterd
 2042 root             1  20    0   311M 17332K kqread  0   3:26   0.00% thirdparty
 1003 root             1  20    0   311M 73132K kqread  0  54:30   0.00% commandd
 1306 root             1  20    0   307M  5364K kqread  0   0:18   0.00% local_authd
 1303 root             1  20    0   305M  7436K kqread  0   0:21   0.00% ftpd.main
 1305 root             1  20    0   301M  1528K kqread  1   0:03   0.00% slbl_db_server
 1837 root             1  20    0   215M 43284K kqread  1   7:01   0.00% counterd
  981 root             1  52    0   196M 18032K kqread  1  10:52   0.00% heimdall
 1353 root             1  20    0   190M 15536K kqread  0   8:18   0.00% trackerd
 2048 root             1  20    0   190M 11036K kqread  0   0:19   0.00% sntpd
 1010 root             1  20    0   188M  6360K kqread  0   0:25   0.00% qlogd
 1308 root             1  20    0   188M  5184K kqread  0   0:18   0.00% ipblockd
 1304 root             1  20    0   188M  4576K kqread  0   0:13   0.00% gatherer
 1669 root             1  20    0   184M  9156K piperd  1   0:01   0.00% external_auth_log
 1478 root             1  20    0   184M  4888K kqread  0   0:13   0.00% ginetd
 2047 root             1  20    0   165M  8780K kqread  0   0:11   0.00% msgs_db_server
```

Comment: That's not a log file. Possible XY problem: Please explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish or solve.

Comment: Is this `top`??

Comment: Well yes this the output of top command and it is being stores in a log file and I was given this log file to parse

Answer (score 0):

You should look at logs with `journalctl` and its `--since` and `--until` parameters, but if you limit yourself to captured `top` displays, you could

```
sed -n -e '/Wed Nov 15 11:02:07 CET 2017/,/Wed Nov 15 11:03:07 CET 2017/p' <top.log
```

Comment: You can also test your filters online with a "regex" checker or download/upload example regex.

Comment: unfortunately nothing comes up when I try to run this command

Comment: Substitute the name of the file you saved the `top` output in

Comment: I have already done that but it does not show anything . Is there a way we can achieve this by shell scripting or somethin. Please guide me how could I achieve it As I have tried grep and sed as well